# How to calculate RAM size from chip markings and number of chips

Tags: ram, markings

I have a RAM with 8 [TMS44400DJ](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/477/TMS44400DJ-70_amp.php) chips on it. It says the word length is 1048576, so would it mean times 8 I have 8MB RAM on this module?

Comment: Each chip is *organized  as  1 048 576  words  of  **four** bits  each*. i.e. 512 KiB. times 8 would only be 4MiB, I think.

Comment: Does it mean, having 4 chips,  1048576 words of 16 bits each I will end up with 8MB RAM? Would the general rule be: number of chips x words × (bits/8)?

Comment: you are overthinking this ... each chip is 4 bits wide ... you need 2 chips to make a byte .... so 2 chips make 1 MiB ... etc. etc.

Comment: It is a 4Mb chip, where the 'b' means bit. 8 * 4Mbit = 32 Mbit = 4 Mbyte.(To be pedantic, all M's should be Mi)